# Godot: How to calculate an angle with multitouch and smoothly add it to camera rotation

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've been struggling for a few days to build multitouch rotation functionality in my godot game and have succesfully managed to incorporate zoom code and simulating multitouch.

One problem I'm facing though is multitouch rotation, I am trying to replicate what Google Maps or Apple Maps does with 2 finger rotation using godot and gdscript. I like how when you rotate in maps it rotates from where you pressed.

I have a 3D scene with a 3D Camera set as orthogonal and I am trying to rotate around the Camera.position.Y

**What is the problem:**
When I use `_camera.rotation.y = _centerScreenVector2.angle_to_point(touchvector) * delta` it feeds the angle directly (the angle being the center point to where I've touched) and the rotation snaps to the new angle, i'd like to calculate the angle where I've touched and where I've travelled to.

I'd imagine it would look something like `_camera.rotation.y = _camera.rotation.y + angleBetweenPoints * delta`

I'll add some of my existing code below, apologies if its badly written (i've ommited a lot of the code that isnt relevant (zoom code and screen orientation code)

```
func _input(event): 
if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
    if event.pressed:
        match event.index:
            0:
                pos_0 = event.position
                pos_0_last_touched = pos_0
                pos_0_valid = true
                pos_0_moved = false
                _line.points[0] = event.position
            1:
                pos_1 = event.position
                pos_1_last_touched = pos_1
                pos_1_valid = true
                pos_1_moved = false
                rotated_pos_1 = pos_1.rotated(_line.points[0].angle_to_point(_line.points[1]))
                _line.points[1] = event.position
                
    else:
        match event.index:
            0:
                pos_0 = Vector2.ZERO
                pos_0_valid = false
                pos_0_moved = false
                distance_prev_valid = false
                
            1:
                pos_1 = Vector2.ZERO
                pos_1_valid = false
                pos_1_moved = false
                distance_prev_valid = false
    elif event is InputEventScreenDrag:
    match event.index:
        0:
            pos_0 = event.position
            pos_0_moved = true
        1:
            pos_1 = event.position  
            pos_1_moved = true
    
        
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    
    deg = rad2deg(_line.points[0].angle_to_point(_line.points[1]))
    
    if (pos_0_valid && pos_1_valid):
       #just testing with 1 finger first 
       camera.rotation.y = test.position.angle_to_point(pos_0)
```

Thank you! please review the image below I've tried to illustrate my problem.

**Further clarification aka TLDR**
If what I wrote above is convoluted and confusing let me try simplify my question
**How can I rotate an orthogonal scene using multitouch where when putting my fingers down and create an arc it smoothly adds to the camera rotation, exactly like you would see in Google maps?**

[image visualising orthogonal rotation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC6LD.jpg)